# polymorphism c++, when making a change to one object all objects change

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am new to polymorphism in c++.  In my constructor I take several objects and create a collection of creatures. When I make a change to one object, it changes all of the same objects.  I am not sure why this is happening.

In my constructor.

```
    lmaxSize=9;
lmiddleSize=6;
lsmallSize=3;
int j=0;
for(int i=0;i<lmaxSize;i++)
{
    if(j=3)
    {
        j=0;
    }
    if(i<lsmallSize)
    {
        creature[i]=&dizzy[j];

    }
    else if(i>=lsmallSize && i<lmiddleSize)
    {
        creature[i]= &pred[j];
    }
    else
    {
        creature[i]=&agile[j];
    }
    j++;
}
```

When I make changes to a pred object, all pred objects change. For example when I use consume energy, it changes the energy for all pred objects.  Do not know why

```
  void collections::consumeEnergy()
{
int creatureNum=0;
cin>>creatureNum;
creature[creatureNum]->consumeEnergyUnits();


  }
```

predatorCreature

```
 void predatorCreature::consumeEnergyUnits()  
  {
       if (_consume < 10)
        {
            _energyUnits -= 2;
            _energyLevel += 1;
        }
        else if (_consume <= 30)
        {
            _energyUnits -= 5;
            _energyLevel += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            _energyUnits -= 7;
            _energyLevel += 4;
        }
 }
```

agileCreature

```
  void agileCreature::consumeEnergyUnits()
{
       if (_consume < 10)
        {
            _energyUnits -= 2;
            _energyLevel += 1;
        }
        else if (_consume <= 30)
        {
            _energyUnits -= 5;
            _energyLevel += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            _energyUnits -= 7;
            _energyLevel += 4;
        }
}
```

Comment: Show us your class definition

Comment: Not enough `std::unique_ptr` in your code.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(j=3)
```

you probably wanted

```
if(j==3)
```

The expression `j=3` will always yield 'true' and you will always do: `j=0;`, and you will later take the same elements from your arrays. [always the first element in each array].

I am not sure it solves the problem - it is a bit hard without more code - but it is most likely a problem.

Comment: @Aaron: Learn to compile with warnings (e.g.: `-Wall`) and don't ignore them. Most compilers emit a warning in this case. This is the case for GCC and Clang.